# Как удалить дубликаты строк из другого файла?

Tags: java

Есть два тестовых файла. Как удалить дубликаты строк из первого файла, которые содержатся в другом файле? Файлы на 500 000 строк и больше. Можно создать новый файл, с результатом.

Comment: а что важнее память или быстродействие?

Comment: даже не знаю, думаю быстродействие)

Answer (score 0):

Implemetation using Java Stream API

```
        String fileFirst = "/home/user/1.txt";//here is your files
        String fileSecond = "/home/user/2.txt";
        String fileResult = "/home/user/1-exclude-2.txt";
        try (Stream<String> streamFirst = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileFirst)); 
                Stream<String> streamSecond = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileSecond))) {
            List<String> list = streamSecond.collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<String> resultList = streamFirst.filter(line -> !list.contains(line)).collect(Collectors.toList());            
            Files.write(Paths.get(fileResult), resultList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: у вас 2 файла по 500 000+ строчек в память загрузяться то?

Comment: Ваш код удаляет все строки из первого файла, которые не содержатся во втором

Comment: 500 000+ для памяти это семечки;) По поводу фильтра - остаются только те строки которых нету во 2 файле, внимательней посмотрите;)

Comment: Да, верно, в любом случае дубликаты он не удаляет

Comment: Возможно не так понял ТЗ. Текущая реализация - код удаляет с первого файла строки, которые содержаться во 2